# Amazon Java client libraries

Tags: soap, amazon-mws

I am developing a  solution for my client for his Amazon account, however, I am unable to find Amazon MWS Java library other than order APIs

I have already looked up everywhere on google, amazon seller forum, etc. but still I am unable to find java libraries other than order API and that even at Maven repository

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to understand how you need to post questions in this community. SO is not for to provide ready made working code.  Show some efforts, what you have tried so far, what errors you got, what you want to achieve? That will help others to understand how to support you. Also your question and the description need more details and clarity.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right directions, however as I mentioned in my question, I am looking for Amazon mws Java client-side libraries, I have looked up extensively on google, amazon forumn, however all the links which points to library are now replaced with registration page and doesnt contains the library. I would appriciate if you have any link of thw library itself which i can use for my application.

Comment: Your question is off-topic here as it is not related to programming.  I suggest to move your question to Super User (delete here, re-post there). You may get more responses to this question in that community.  Also, I suggest you to contact Amazon support team if you are not able to get an answer from any of these communities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got in touch with Amazon Seller support and they sent me a link where Libraries for Amazon MWS Java, PhP and .Net are available. If anyone in future need it, they can find it here: https://developer.amazonservices.in/tools

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, they moved the client libraries and you must first sign in to a professional sellers account to access them.  They were available publicly for years.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "amazon mws java" returns links like https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/orders/orders/v20130901/java.html which require a Developer account (which in MWS terms means only the org's dev primary account as no General Role dev-enabled accounts in an org can get in, only primary and note that is different than the org's primary primary account). Best is whoever has it, post to open source GitHub before MWS reverts client libraries back to primary-only view ignoring they're almost a decade old now.